# How to proper sign in a user using SignInManager in asp mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I tried creating a simple asp mvc application where I can register and log in users. The registration part seems to be working, the users are correctly saved in the database, but the login functionality seems to not be functioning. After the login, I can not endpoints in the controller on which I put the `[Authorize]`  attribute. Also in my navigation bar, the "register" and "Login" buttons are supposed to disappear if a user is logged in but they don't. So how can I  fix this issue?

Here is my code:

The Controller log in methods:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginPost(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //var result = await this._service.SignInWithPassAsync(model.Username,
            //    model.Password, model.RememberMe);

            var result = await this._signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);

            if(result.Succeeded)
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            throw new ArgumentException("Login failed!");
        }
        else
            //Invalid Model state. Repeat Login
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "Problem with Login occurred! Please try again!");

    }
```

The service methods:

```
    public async Task<SignInResult> SignInWithPassAsync(string username,
                string password, bool rememberMe)
            {
                return await this._signInManager
                    .PasswordSignInAsync(username, password,
                        rememberMe, false);
            }
```

The LoginViewModel:

```
            public class LoginViewModel
        {
            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string Username { get; set; }
    
            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }
    
            [Display(Name = "Remember Me")]
            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }
```

And the View where the navigation bar is:

```
    @if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                            {
                                <div>Welcome <a asp-action="UserProfile" asp-controller="Account" asp-route-id="@UserManager.GetUserId(User)">@UserManager.GetUserName(User)</a></div>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Login</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">Register</a>
                                </li>
                            }
```

Comment: Can you share your `startup` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my test, the problem may caused by your `startup` class.

The order of the middleware should be as follows.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Controller code:

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
   
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
  

    public YourController(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {           
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }
  [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }
  [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
  [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginPost(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

             var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            throw new ArgumentException("Login failed!");
        }
        else
            //Invalid Model state. Repeat Login
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "Problem with Login occurred! Please try again!");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Startup.cs

public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            //services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
               .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
               .AddDefaultUI()
               .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddTransient<IPatientRepository,PatientRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IDoctorRepository, DoctorRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IAppointmentRepository, AppointmentsRepository>();
            var context = new CustomAssemblyLoadContext();
            context.LoadUnmanagedLibrary(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "libwkhtmltox.dll"));
            services.AddSingleton(typeof(IConverter), new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools()));
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddElmah<SqlErrorLog>(options => {
                options.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            });
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
            //services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
            //    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Account/Login", "");
            //}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
            //services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            //    options.UseSqlServer(
            //        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnectionString")));
            //services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Account/Login", "");
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
           

            //services.Configure<EmailSender>(Configuration.GetSection("Myconfig"));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
          
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseElmah();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }


    }   


 Login Code For SignIn and Roles
    
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                        if (result.Succeeded)
                        {
                            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.Email);
                            var role = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
                            string RoleName = string.Empty;
                            foreach (var Role in role.Result)
                            {
                                RoleName = Role;
                            }
                            if (RoleName == "Admin")
                            {
                                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Appointments.Dashboard), "Appointments");
                            }
                            if (RoleName == "Patient")
                            {
                                return RedirectToAction(nameof(PatientsController.Index), "Patients");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return RedirectToAction(nameof(DoctorsController.Index), "Doctors");
                            }
                        }
                        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                        {
                            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                        }
                        if (result.IsLockedOut)
                        {
                            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                            return Page();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: I see you are new here. first of all thank you for your answer, but could you as som explanation to you code. This would make the answer al lot more clear